# Pandas: Add the value based on certain conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm new to Pandas. I have a data frame that looks something like this.

| Name | Storage Location | Total Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | S1 | 100 |
| a | S2 | 200 |
| a | S3 | 300 |
| a | S4 | 110 |
| a | S5 | 200 |
| b | S1 | 200 |
| b | S2 | 300 |
| b | S4 | 400 |
| b | S5 | 150 |
| c | S1 | 400 |
| c | S5 | 500 |

I wanna sum the "**Total Quantity**" group by the **Name** and also **specific storage location** which are only "**S1,S2,S3**".

| Name | Total Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| a | 600 |
| b | 500 |
| c | 400 |

My desired output would be something like the above.
Kindly appreciate for you guys help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `where` to replace the unwanted Locations with NaN and use `groupby` + `sum` (since `sum` skips NaN by default):

```
out = df.where(df['Storage Location'].isin(['S1','S2','S3'])).groupby('Name', as_index=False)['Total Quantity'].sum()
```

Output:

```
  Name  Total Quantity
0    a           600.0
1    b           500.0
2    c           400.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
In [2378]: out = df[df['Storage Location'].isin(['S1', 'S2', 'S3'])].groupby('Name')['Total Quantity'].sum().reset_index()

In [2379]: out
Out[2379]: 
  Name  Total Quantity
0    a             600
1    b             500
2    c             400
```